# how do i get an element that is selected

Tags: css

so I have this code

```
#id {
 border-color: blue;
}
```

and ID is a text area

how do I do `#id::??? {}`
and I want to make it so when I select the text area I what to make the outline color different

how do I do that?

Comment: you can use `:focus` eg `#id:focus {}`

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `pseudo class`. There are many pseudo classes. Also, there are `pseudo elements`.  Do read them on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `border` or `box-shadow:` for `:focus` pseudo class.

CSS `focus` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

**Edit:**
Width resize can be done with `resize: horizontal;`

If you want to resize the height try setting `resize: vertical;` for `textarea`

CSS `resize` [Reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

```css
#id {
  border-color: blue;
  resize: horizontal;
}

#id:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid green;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2eff00;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="id" name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: yes that works for me
but how do i make it so i can only allow width resizing?

Comment: @Natejoestev Width resize can be done with `resize: horizontal;`. Updated that in answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggle element state to change element
Ex: `#id:focus`

Answer (score 0):

Using `:focus` Psuedo class you can change any property of that element when it is focused!

```css
#myTextArea { border-color: blue; }
#myTextArea:focus { outline-color: tomato; }
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

---

You can use `resize: vertical` to allow user to only resize it vertically

Example:

```css
#myTextArea { resize: vertical; }
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

---

Or You can use `resize: horizontal;` to allow user to only resize it horizontally

Example:

```css
#myTextArea { resize: horizontal; }
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Or you can use `resize: none` which will not allow user to resize that text area

---

Read More about [`:focus` Pseudo Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Read More about [`resize` Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)